# Jquery Inserting a textarea dynamically and detect new letters entered

Tags: jquery

I am inserting a textarea dynamically, it has a content, now if user enter new content, I have to store new + old content into hidden field.

I used an `.live('change',function() {  } });` but this is not working. Which event should I use to trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead of `change`, the change will fire when the focus goes out of textbox. `live` is deprecated you better use `on` instead.

```
.live('keyup',function() { } });
```

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Using on for binding dynamically added textarea.

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".textAreaClass", function(){
   alert("");
});
```

`document` in selector could be repalced by `parent` element selector

Comment: $('#hiddenFieldId').val($('#textAreaId').val());

Comment: how to remove a textarea with out removing contents inside it ?

Comment: Removing textarea without removing its contents is not possible, but before removing the textarea you can save contents to some variable or control and then remove the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keyup` event because it generated when user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

And also use `.on()` because `.live()` is deprecated from new version of `jQuery`.

```
.on('keyup',function() { } });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 <textarea rows="3" cols="50"  name="" id="qcnotes" class="input-xlarge focused" style="width:100%" placeholder="Enter Notes" onkeyup="functionname(this.value)"></textarea>
```